# How to remove white spacing between table cells in Edge Browser

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have following html table:

Home
                                        
                        
                
                
                        
                                
                                
                                Booking Requests
                                
                        
                
                
                        
                                
                                
                                School Profile
                                
                        
                
                
                        

                                
                                
                                Booking Help

**CSS**

```
.navBarItemContainer {
    background-color:#e5e5e5;width:25%;display:inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color:black;
    height:90px;
}
.navBarItemContainer_selected {
    background-color:#efefef;width:25%;display:inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    border-bottom:4px solid #fece00;
    color:black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height:90px;
}
noBordertable, .noBordertable td {
    border:0;background:none;margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/927hL4wj/)

On google chrome browser, it works fine but on new **Edge** browser it shows white space between table cells (`<td>`s) and hence last `td` is shown in next line. What should I do to fix it in edge brower?

Comment: May I ask why you use the `table` element for layout? ... and you really shouldn't use both inline and external styles together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do only one thing remove space/break line between `</td>` and new `<td>` will solve your issue.

Because you are using `display:inline-block` and it will count every space between end element and start element.

So it should be like:

```
</td><td style="padding:0;margin:0;border-collapse: collapse;" class="navBarItemContainer">
```

Not:

```
</td>
<td style="padding:0;margin:0;border-collapse: collapse;" class="navBarItemContainer">
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/927hL4wj/2/)**

[Check for more information](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to really make them inline:

So instead of this:

```
<td>

</td>
<td>

</td>
```

make it like this:

```
<td>

</td><td>

</td>
```

or you may have it like this:

```
<td>

</td><!--
--><td>

</td>
```

or you may put the last character at the new line:

```
<td>

</td
><td>

</td>
```

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) has a full story about **Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements** which you may want to take a look.